# Natural probability density on the unit disk

Tags: probability, complex-analysis, statistics

I need a probability density for random complex numbers inside the unit disk. I would like it to be as "simple" and "natural" as possible, ambiguous as these terms may be.

I would like this function to be zero at the boundary $|z|=1$, to have a single  "hump" inside the disk, i.e. to be unimodal, with a prescribed real mode $z_0$, and to be concave.

(For $z_0=0$ a natural solution would be $1-|z|^2$.)

Any suggestions?